# SQL - datediff returns hours, but I want to add minutes and seconds in HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, date-difference

I am looking to adapt my existing code to account for minutes and seconds elapsed between two `datetime` values. I currently pull out the hours passed, but it would be best if instead of just hours, it was in a HH:MM:SS format but I can't seem to find any documents that solve my problem.

```
Select 
    convert(datetime, Left(Replace(Create_Date, 'T', ' '), 19)) as CreateDate2,
    case 
       when Resolution_date = 'None' then '1999-01-01 12:00:00'
       when Resolution_date <> 'None' then convert(datetime, left(replace(resolution_date, 'T', ' '), 19))
    end as ResolutionDate2,
    datediff(hour, convert(datetime, left(replace(Create_Date, 'T', ' '), 19)), 
    case 
       when Resolution_date = 'None' then '1999-01-01 12:00:00'
       when Resolution_date <> 'None' then convert(datetime, left(replace(Resolution_date, 'T', ' '), 19)) 
    end) as HoursPassed,
    *
from 
    xyz 
where 
    abc;
```

More specifically, this section from the above code:

```
datediff(hour, convert(datetime,Left(Replace(Create_Date, 'T', ' '), 19)), 
case 
    when Resolution_date = 'None' then '1999-01-01 12:00:00'
    when Resolution_date <> 'None' then convert(datetime, left(replace(Resolution_date, 'T', ' '), 19)) 
end) as HoursPassed
```

The `datetime` column initially comes in this format:

```
2017-05-25T15:58:26.000+0000
```

Results currently look like this:

```
2017-05-23 19:51:59.000  2017-05-24 12:38:17.000        17
2017-05-24 15:10:50.000  2017-05-24 16:31:23.000         1
2017-05-25 15:58:26.000  2017-05-25 16:03:30.000         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the number of seconds as a time.  I don't easily follow the logic of your code, but the conversion is simple enough:

```
select cast(dateadd(second,
                    datediff(second, <starttime>, <enddatime>),
                    0) as time
           )
```

Comment: This results in a error of `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` - which is why I wanted to use the existing code in some way or somehow, because it scrubs out the 'none' from the column that causes the error.

Comment: @EricKing . . . Then plug your expressions for the conversion into this.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff - I didn't realize what you meant at first, but I was able to plug it in like so and it seems to work as we intended:  `,cast(dateadd(second, datediff(second, convert(datetime,Left(Replace(Create_Date, 'T', ' '), 19)), convert(datetime,Left(Replace(Resolution_Date, 'T', ' '), 19))), 0) as time)`